# Best Modern Approach To CSS Image Replacement

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I've tried pretty much every method out there to hide the text contents of my page title (h1 tag) and display an image instead.  Below is the closest I've come but it's got an annoying flaw...  the height of the h1 remains fixed and does not shrink to the reduced height of the background image.  Are there any other ways to solve this?

```
<style>
    max-width:660px; 
    min-height:150px; 
    background: url('/images/theTitleBkgrdImage.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
</style>

<h1 class="pgTitle">This is the page title</h1>
```

Comment: Why not use an image tag instead of this weird thing you are trying to do?

Comment: If you want to toggle between two tags, you can use javascript to set the display to block and hidden and vice versa, depending on the situation.

Comment: Because Google and screen readers cannot read the contents of my image to know what the page title is.  All pages should start with an H1 tag.

Comment: Can't you just set its `height` to the height of the image?

Comment: Andrew I would love to but so far nothing seems to work.  I can set the height of the h1 to the normal image height but not to the smaller when the image shrinks down for the smaller responsive view.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `alt` attribute in your image, bots and screen readers will understand that text belongs in the `h1`.

```
<h1><img alt="This is the page title" src="/images/theTitleBkgrdImage.jpg" /></h1>
```

Comment: Articles I have recently read say that is the wrong way to do it.  Has that changed?  That's why my question asks about the current modern method.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko I would disagree that this is the "wrong" way. Different strategies accommodate different scenarios. The strategy you've provided in your question will fail if a browser has CSS enabled but images disabled (the text will be pushed out of view but the image replacement won't render). The approach I've provided at least works regardless of the state of CSS and Images in the browser. [Here is a good article](https://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/) showing alternative solutions, but each has potential failure points.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko Also, I would like to point out that the examples provided by the W3 pertaining to images of text suggest the format I've provided, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#images-of-text

Comment: Although the examples provided might still work, they are however over 8 years old. Are they the recommended method for today's modern browsers?  I am finding so much outdated and conflicting information.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. The CSS tricks article I provided does show outdated examples of alternative strategies using CSS and whatnot. The W3 article that I provided in my second comment is the actual W3 recommendation that browsers are designed to accommodate. I've always used the W3 specifications as the definitive resource for providing the most accurate and useful information. That is why I am recommending it in my answer.

Comment: Here is a good discussion but I don't see anything about responsive:  http://www.loganfranken.com/blog/1244/do-we-still-need-image-replacement/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111471/discussion-between-quantastical-and-connie-decinko).